# How to speedup non-sequential array filling?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

**Context**

I have a code like this:

```
..
vector<int> values = ..., vector<vector<int>> buckets;
//reserve space for values and each buckets sub-vector
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
  buckets[values[i]].push_back(i);
}
...
```

So I get a "buckets" with indexes of entries that have same value. Those buckets are used then in further processing.

Actually I'm working with native dynamic arrays (`int ** buckets;`) but for simplicity's sake I've used vectors above.

I know the size of each bucket before filling.

Size of vectors is about 2,000,000,000.

**The problem**

As you can see the code above access "buckets" array in a random manner. Thus it have constant cache misses that slows execution time dramatically.
Yes, I see such misses in profile report.

**Question**

*Is there a way to improve speed of such code?*

I've tried to create a aux vector and put first occurrence of value there thus I can put two indexes in corresponding bucket as I found second one. This approach didn't give any speedup.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Use a smaller type than `int`.

Comment: @Pubby how will I store indexes of range 0..2,000,000,000 in smaller type?

Comment: can you compute the inverse of foo() easily? (if it is indeed lightweight, post it, it may give people ideas...)

Comment: Well, what is the current performance? 2,000,000,000 int's is about 7GiB of data. Chances are you don't have enough ram for a whole bunch of those buckets...

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan you mean to get index of "values" by foo result? It's possible only by iteration whole values set

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan I've checked once again. that foo() can be completely removed - just value used as index.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do anyways? Bucket-sort 2 billion entries with one bucket per possible final value? Try radix sort to at least reduce the number of buckets... merge-sort will probably result in the least page-faults (and it's inplace so you don't need 14GiB ram).

Comment: @example yes, number of buckets can be changed. Currently I'm using 65K buckets. But if I decrease this count to say 256 then I'll have to sort result buckets once again and take cache misses on values array because of randomness...

Comment: I have 16Gb RAM. Currently it takes about 6 sec to process 200,000,000 values (10% of target). And it's a longest operation in whole processing routine

Comment: if you want to sort the array and the cache misses are the limiting factor then clearly a bucket sort is not the right thing to do. It seems to be a major part of the whole routine so i would suggest a parallel (inplace) merge sort.

Comment: @example thank you for this advice. I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assuming it's cache misses that make your code slow? Have you profiled or is that just what came to mind?

There's a number of things very wrong with your code from a performance perspective. The first and most obvious is that you never reserve a vector size. What's happening is that your vector is starting out very small (say, 2 elements), then each time you add past the size, it'll resize again *and copy the contents over to the new memory location*. If you're saying there are 2 *billion* entries, you're resizing maybe 30 times!

You *need* to call the function `vector.reserve()` (or `vector.resize()`, depending on what behavior works best for you) before you look at other improvements.

EDIT

Seriously? You mention that you're not even using a vector in your PS? How are we supposed to guess what your actual code looks like and how it will perform?

Comment: as you can see in "P.S." I'm using native arrays and allocate them before the lool

Comment: Seriously? You mention that you're not even using a vector in your PS? How are we supposed to guess what your actual code looks like and how it will perform? The code you posted has zero bearing on the question you're asking.

Comment: @bitmask he says "native dynamic array" which, in C++, is a vector, no?

Comment: @Mahmoud my guess is he meant native (dynamically allocated) arrays.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi You think that voting down a question that you dind't read to the end is a good practice? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is `foo` at least **reversible and surjective** for a given interval? Then you can run through that interval and fill `buckets[j]` completely with `bar(j,k)` (if `bar` is the inverse of `foo`), for `k` in `[0,...,MAX_BAR_J)`, then continue with `j+1` and so forth.

If however `foo` has hashing properties, you have very little chance, because you cannot predict to which index the next `i` will get you. So I see no chance right now.

Comment: yea, this function is like a hash. Moreover it's can be completely removed and only values will be used as index of bucket. Sorry for such unclear statements.